# How to delete a line from a docx document using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a Docx file that contains only text and I want to modify it using python-docx.

I want to delete empty lines and lines that have a specific style.

Here is what I tried:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('sample.docx')
lines = doc.paragraphs


for line in lines:
    #delete empty lines
    if len(line.text) == 0:
        lines.remove(line)
        continue
    #delete line if it has this specifc style
    if line.runs[0].font.name == 'Formata-Regular' and line.runs[0].font.size.pt == float(8.0):
        line.clear()


doc.save('output.docx')
```

`line.clear()` works - it only removes the content of the line but does not delete it.

`lines.remove(line)` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I found this piece of code (written by scanny [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33)) and it gets the job done

```
def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    p._p = p._element = None
```

here is how my code looks now:

```
import docx

def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    p._p = p._element = None

doc = docx.Document('sample.docx')
lines = doc.paragraphs

for line in lines:
    #delete empty lines
    if len(line.text) == 0:
        delete_paragraph(line)
        continue
    #delete line if it has this specifc style
    if line.runs[0].font.name == 'Formata-Regular' and line.runs[0].font.size.pt == float(8.0):
        delete_paragraph(line)


doc.save('output.docx')
```

All empty lines (or lines with that specific style) gets deleted.

Comment: It appears the last line is incorrect according to this github issue: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-551891907

Should be `paragraph._p = paragraph._element = None`